# Error while concatenating nested list string to a list of strings

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I have a nested lists contain string example as

```
[['abc','abc df','pqr'],['xyz','efg']]
```

I want to concatenate the this nested list into one list of strings such as

```
['abc','abc df','pqr','xyz','efg']
```

like that. i use the the code

```
all_tokens = sum(text, [])
```

but its bringing me the error saying

```
can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Why its happening like that?  how to fix the error? also what are the alternative methods to do the same task?

EDIT

i know iterate through a for loop can manage the same thing. but i am searching for a fast method

Comment: Your code is working fine for me.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary i am using very long list of documents . May be somewhere is a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce`, it goes through the lists and concatenate them.

```
l=[['abc','abc df','pqr'],['xyz','efg']]
print reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,l)
```

**Output:**

```
['abc', 'abc df', 'pqr', 'xyz', 'efg']
```

You can use nested loops in List comprehension as well

```
print [item for subL in l for item in subL]
```

You can sum the list, using `sum()`

```
print sum(l, [])
```

You can also use `itertools.chain()`

```
from itertools import chain
print list(chain(*l))
```

It would give the same result.

Comment: Thanks taha. works like a magic

Answer (score 2):

Some example code would be good to have, but I assume you have a list of lists you would like to 'concatenate' into one list. Here is how it could be done:

```
a = [['abc','abc df','pqr'],['xyz','efg']]
b = []
for element in a:
    b.extend(element)
```

It will not check for duplicate elements. To do so, you can use `set` to make sure each element is present only once:

```
mylist = list(set(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

use itertools.chain like so:

```
from itertools import chain
x = chain.from_iterable([['abc','abc df','pqr'],['xyz','efg']])
# you can also make a list out of it, if you need to
x = list(x)
```